# matlab omiting milliseconds from datenum

Tags: matlab

Let

```
x=7.369030000162731e+05
```

x is a matlab date and it is equal to

```
27.07.2017 00:00:01.406
```

I want to remove the milliseconds from it (ie. .406)

To do this I convert it to datestr with 'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS' format
and then again to datenum

```
datenum(datestr(x,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS'))
```

Is there a simpler way to do this.

Comment: For what it is worth, you can't accurately compare your approach with the answers below because of a subtle bug here (at least for my locale).  Your date format string is different from what `datenum` is expecting and the result is changed to from July 27, 2017 to January 1, 2017 (for me).  One way to fix this is to explicitly pass the format string as  a second parameter to `datenum` like this: `datenum(datestr(x,'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS'),'dd.mm.yyyy HH:MM:SS'))`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the manual approach:

```
y = floor(x*86400)/86400;
```

because [serial date numbers](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) are measured in days, and `86400` is the number of seconds in a day.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a somewhat simpler way that converts `x` to a [date vector](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html), [floors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) all the elements (which only affects the seconds value in index 6), then converts it back to a [serial date number](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html):

```
x = datenum(floor(datevec(x)));
```

Comment: I always forget about `datevec`, haven't had enough use-cases yet to be fluent in handling dates. Congrats on the 100k, just needed a simple date formatting question to push you over ;)